# TYPO3 9.5 Form Extension add custom value to finisher email

Tags: forms, typo3

I have custom finisher where I want to add new fiele value so that I can use this value in email template of email finisher. In my custom finisher action I add value:

```
$this->finisherContext->getFinisherVariableProvider()->add(
        $this->shortFinisherIdentifier,
        'jsonfile',
        $yourCustomOptionPfad.$guidName.'.json'
    );
```

In email template I can see value if I debug, but if I add {finisherVariableProvider.objects.MyCustomActionsave.jsonfile} to template, I get error:

```
Cannot access protected property TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Finishers\FinisherVariableProvider::$objects
```

Hope you can help me to get cutom value in email template!
Martin

Answer (score -1):

Found solution:

```
$this->finisherContext->getFormRuntime()->offsetSet(...);
```